# How to loop through a list of dict to get a specific value?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary

How can I get all the titles from below list of dict. The title field is stored in the 'data' key and in some case the data key can be an empty list.

```
all_movies = [{'page': '1',
               'per_page': 10,
               'total': 13,
               'total_pages': 2,
               'data': [{'Title': 'Italian Spiderman', 'Year': 2007, 'imdbID': 'tt2705436'},
                        {'Title': 'Superman, Spiderman or Batman',
                         'Year': 2011,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2084949'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman', 'Year': 1990, 'imdbID': 'tt0100669'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman', 'Year': 2010, 'imdbID': 'tt1785572'},
                        {'Title': 'Fighting, Flying and Driving: The Stunts of Spiderman 3',
                         'Year': 2007,
                         'imdbID': 'tt1132238'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman and Grandma', 'Year': 2009, 'imdbID': 'tt1433184'},
                        {'Title': 'The Amazing Spiderman T4 Premiere Special',
                         'Year': 2012,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2233044'},
                        {'Title': 'Amazing Spiderman Syndrome',
                         'Year': 2012,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2586634'},
                        {'Title': "Hollywood's Master Storytellers: Spiderman Live",
                         'Year': 2006,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2158533'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman 5', 'Year': 2008, 'imdbID': 'tt3696826'}]},
              {'page': '2',
               'per_page': 10,
               'total': 13,
               'total_pages': 2,
               'data': [{'Title': 'They Call Me Spiderman',
                         'Year': 2016,
                         'imdbID': 'tt5861236'},
                        {'Title': 'The Death of Spiderman', 'Year': 2015, 'imdbID': 'tt5921428'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman in Cannes', 'Year': 2016, 'imdbID': 'tt5978586'}]},
              {'page': '3', 'per_page': 10, 'total': 13, 'total_pages': 2, 'data': []}]
```

This is the output I need:

```
title = ['Amazing Spiderman Syndrome',
'Fighting, Flying and Driving: The Stunts of Spiderman 3',
"Hollywood's Master Storytellers: Spiderman Live",
'Italian Spiderman',
'Spiderman',
'Spiderman',
'Spiderman 5',
'Spiderman and Grandma',
'Superman, Spiderman or Batman',
'The Amazing Spiderman T4 Premiere Special']
```

```
all_title = []
for movie in all_movies:
    title = movie['data']
    all_title.append(title)
```

This gives me a list of list of dict as below but I am not able to get the Title using list index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

with something like this I think

```
  titles = []
  for movie in all_movies:
    title_list = movie.get("data", [])
    for title in title_list:
      if title.get('Title'):
        titles.append(title.get('Title'))

  print(titles)
```

Consider using `get` with default param if key is missing

Answer (score 1):

@vx3r's answer is simpler but for the sake of completeness - the same using comprehensions:

```
import itertools
import json

all_movies = [{'page': '1',
               'per_page': 10,
               'total': 13,
               'total_pages': 2,
               'data': [{'Title': 'Italian Spiderman', 'Year': 2007, 'imdbID': 'tt2705436'},
                        {'Title': 'Superman, Spiderman or Batman',
                         'Year': 2011,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2084949'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman', 'Year': 1990, 'imdbID': 'tt0100669'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman', 'Year': 2010, 'imdbID': 'tt1785572'},
                        {'Title': 'Fighting, Flying and Driving: The Stunts of Spiderman 3',
                         'Year': 2007,
                         'imdbID': 'tt1132238'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman and Grandma', 'Year': 2009, 'imdbID': 'tt1433184'},
                        {'Title': 'The Amazing Spiderman T4 Premiere Special',
                         'Year': 2012,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2233044'},
                        {'Title': 'Amazing Spiderman Syndrome',
                         'Year': 2012,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2586634'},
                        {'Title': "Hollywood's Master Storytellers: Spiderman Live",
                         'Year': 2006,
                         'imdbID': 'tt2158533'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman 5', 'Year': 2008, 'imdbID': 'tt3696826'}]},
              {'page': '2',
               'per_page': 10,
               'total': 13,
               'total_pages': 2,
               'data': [{'Title': 'They Call Me Spiderman',
                         'Year': 2016,
                         'imdbID': 'tt5861236'},
                        {'Title': 'The Death of Spiderman', 'Year': 2015, 'imdbID': 'tt5921428'},
                        {'Title': 'Spiderman in Cannes', 'Year': 2016, 'imdbID': 'tt5978586'}]},
              {'page': '3', 'per_page': 10, 'total': 13, 'total_pages': 2, 'data': []}]

# get all 'data' contents together, then flattened
datas = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable([l.get('data', []) for l in all_movies]))
# extract only titles, all of them
all_titles = [k.get('Title') for k in datas]
print(json.dumps(all_titles, indent=2))
```

Output:

```
[
  "Italian Spiderman",
  "Superman, Spiderman or Batman",
  "Spiderman",
  "Spiderman",
  "Fighting, Flying and Driving: The Stunts of Spiderman 3",
  "Spiderman and Grandma",
  "The Amazing Spiderman T4 Premiere Special",
  "Amazing Spiderman Syndrome",
  "Hollywood's Master Storytellers: Spiderman Live",
  "Spiderman 5",
  "They Call Me Spiderman",
  "The Death of Spiderman",
  "Spiderman in Cannes"
]
```

You have some duplicated entries. If this is not what you want, use a set instead of a list:

```
all_titles = {k.get('Title') for k in datas}
```